# Best practice for core data model object save

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, xcode6

I have a two entity "Person" and "Car" is coming from the web service.
I need to store that in sqlite through core data. I want to know what is the best approach should i bind the save method with NSmanagedobject or write differently in utility or manager?

```
**Approach 1** 

@interface Person : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * title;

- (void) saveManagedObject:(NSDictionary*)response //Responsible for init the person object and save in context

@end

**Approach 2**

@interface CoreDataUtility : NSObject

- (void) saveManagedObject:(NSDictionary*)response //Responsible for create the person object and save in context

@end
```

Comment: Side note on this, any methods you add to your `NSManagedObject` classes you should do in a category. If you change your `CoreData` layout and regenerate files your methods will be lost.

Comment: Thanks for the note :).

Comment: Can you please suggest me the good approach?

Comment: @SauravNagpal Hi. Best practice for CoreData - [Mogenerator](https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator) + [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord)

Comment: @SauravNagpal Take a look at THIS TUTORIAL https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N2sZ9IjDBzs

Comment: @Mozilla Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: both methods are good, especially if you do not want to deal with 3rd party frameworks. Those might be useful, but the also bear some risks; this would be another question.

It is perfectly fine to have a creation method in the `NSManagedObject´ subclass (in a category or elsewhere*).

However, you should make it a **class** method, not an instance method.

To create an entity in a `DataManager` class is also a feasible and a very common pattern. The good thing about the utility class is that you can more easily maintain multiple contexts for background operations.

*) *I do not use categories any more because it is rare to change the model by more than a few fields- I prefer to edit them manually.*